# Jquery not working within wordpress content

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a very simple piece of jquery code(sliding a piece of text up) based upon clicking on a div.

```
<script>
jQuery("#test").click(function () {
    jQuery(this).slideUp();
});
</script>
```

This works when the

```
<div id="test">some text</div>
```

is placed outside the main content of the page, so in the header or the footer, but it doesn't work when the `<div id="test">some text</div>` is placed within the content part.

I have searched the internet for a solution, but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that code is executed on DOM ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#test").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Explanation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).ready function as a wrapper for your code.